# ps_mainmeu in prestashop1.7 dropdown is not working

Tags: prestashop-1.7

im new to prestashop. i have problems with ps_mainmenu module as bellow:
1. there are two collapse icons(up^ and down) at the left side of the menu which are not supposed to be.
2. the dropdown functionality is not working and after multiple clicking sometimes appears and disappears quickly.
my tpl file is like that:

```
        {assign var=_counter value=0}
{function name="menu" nodes=[] depth=0 parent=null}
    {if $nodes|count}
      <ul class="top-menu" {if $depth == 0}id="top-menu"{/if} data-depth="{$depth}">
        {foreach from=$nodes item=node}
            <li class="{$node.type}{if $node.current} current {/if}" id="{$node.page_identifier}">
            {assign var=_counter value=$_counter+1}
              <a
                class="{if $depth >= 0}dropdown-item{/if}{if $depth === 1} dropdown-submenu{/if}"
                href="{$node.url}" data-depth="{$depth}"
                {if $node.open_in_new_window} target="_blank" {/if}
              >
                {if $node.children|count}
                  {* Cannot use page identifier as we can have the same page several times *}
                  {assign var=_expand_id value=10|mt_rand:100000}
                  <span class="float-xs-right hidde-md-none">
                    <span data-target="#top_sub_menu_{$_expand_id}" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
                      <i class="material-icons add">&#xE313;</i>
                      <i class="material-icons remove">&#xE316;</i>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                {/if}
                {$node.label}
              </a>
              {if $node.children|count}
              <div {if $depth === 0} class="popover sub-menu js-sub-menu collapse"{else} class="collapse"{/if} id="top_sub_menu_{$_expand_id}">
                {menu nodes=$node.children depth=$node.depth parent=$node}
              </div>
              {/if}
            </li>
        {/foreach}
      </ul>
    {/if}
{/function}

<div class="menu js-top-menu position-static d-none d-md-block" id="_desktop_top_menu">
    {menu nodes=$menu.children}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some javascript errors on your website pages (on console)?

Comment: no i already compared the top-menu.js file with the default and there are no difference.. also mainmenu.scss and .php files

Comment: What is the version of PrestaShop and the module? Are you using the default theme?